# How can I unathorized view in Google BigQuery via API or CLI

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

There is not in an official document or anyone mentioned it.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step 1

Enter the following command to write the access controls for yourdataset to a JSON file. yourdataset is in yourproject.

```
bq show --format=prettyjson \ yourproject:yourdataset > /tmp/yourdataset.json
```

- Step 2

Make your changes to the "access" section of the JSON file.

- Step 3

When your edits are complete, use the update command and include the JSON file using the --source flag. Note: when you apply the JSON file that contains the access controls, the existing access controls are overwritten.

```
bq update --source /tmp/yourdataset.json yourdataset
```

If the dataset is in a project other than your default project, add the project ID to the dataset name in the following format: project_id:dataset.

Comment: In addition to this, and answering to the original question, there is in fact GCP documentation about managing views: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-views

Comment: Thank you very much, by the way, I found the way to use API which has the same behaviour as you mentioned. Just get Dataset.access_entries then delete section "view" in retuned dictionary, finally update this dataset after removing the view from it.